# Strange cron behavior...mysterious "Applications" not found

Tags: macos, cron

I'm running the following cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch test.file
cp test.file test.test
```

With the following cron:

```
33 17 * * * * ~/Utils/test.sh
```

And I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: Applications: command not found
```

Any help?

Comment: On OS X / macOS, cron has been deprecated in favour of launchd. I suggest changing to use that instead, which is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-SW7). In addition, you should probably specify the full path to the script, rather than using '~' for your home directory.

Comment: I didn't realize that. Let me at least update to a full path...not sure if I'm going to bother using launchd. Maybe, heh.

Answer (score 2):

My own fault - I had an extra * in the time definition.

```
33 17 * * * * ~/Utils/test.sh
```

VS

```
33 17 * * * ~/Utils/test.sh
```